# Angular 2 render page without router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have HTML template with slide menu and top nav menu and block for render main path page.
like this:

```
...
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
...
```

But after it, my login page render in this **content-wrapper** block. 
How to write some code for render **LoginPage** without **route-outline** component? (for not render top nav and slide menus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the router-outlet, but use the router guards to prevent the route from being rendered unless the user logged in. I blogged about it here:

https://yakovfain.com/2016/07/20/angular-2-guarding-routes/

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution to your problem is not go around `router-outlet`, but using one extra component (lets call it `RootComponent`) with `router-outlet` (RO1), but without nav and side menu. In RO1 you should load either your component `NavMenuComponent` (with the nav, side menu and its own `router-outlet` RO2). Then you can use child routes to ensure that in RO1 in `RootComponent` is loaded either `NavMenuComponent` (which will have nav and side menu) or `LoginComponent` (which will have no nav and side menu). In RO2 will be loaded the content as you have it now.

Assuming `RootComponent` is the deafult component in your module, routes will look like this:

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'app', component: NavMenuComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'youorldpath1', component: YourOld1Component }, //the path will /app/youroldpath1 instead of /youroldpath1
      { path: 'youorldpath2', component: YourOld2Component, canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard] },
      { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
    ]
  },

  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }

];
```

`RootComponent` can have only :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to hide the Top Nav and Slide Menu from users that aren't logged in.

My method for doing this is to pull those controls/components out of the pages you are rendering in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and then hide them until a user is logged in (probably via a boolean property on the authentication service that shows a user has successfully logged in).

So something similar to this:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <top-nav *ngIf="authenticationService.userLoggedIn"></top-nav>
    <slide-menu *ngIf="authenticationService.userLoggedIn"></slide-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The login page renders in the router outlet, and when a user logs in successfully, the flag is set on the service, and the next page is rendered and the Top Nav/Slide Menu are added to the DOM.

If I'm way off base, let me know and maybe I can still help out

Comment: I think it is not very good solutions. And I think exists some standard solutions.

Comment: So, just to make sure I am understanding what you are trying to do, you want to render the Top Nav and the Slide Menu and have it on each page you render in the `<router-outlet>`.  The only time you don't want them to render is when they hit the login page?

Comment: I'm not sure of how you have the environment setup, but the only way I can think of to do what you are looking to do is to build a separate static login page, and on successful login, redirect to the Angular app.  That's definitely not the best/easiest way to do it, but based on what I have on your architecture, that's the way that will work.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution working in my app.**

Create Login component with just login page content.

Create TopNav Component.

Create SideNav Component.

Create The other component(Lets say Admin) you want to show after Login with Top Nav, Side Nav and other Stuff you want to show to the logged in users.

**Route them in the Module like this...**

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
   path: 'admin', 
   component: AdminComponent
 }
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>

  <!-- When your route is '/login' login component rendered here.
  If it is '/admin' admin component rendered here -->
<router-outlet>
```

login.component.html

```
//login page content
```

admin.component.html

```
 <app-top-nav></app-top-nav>
 <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
 <div class="content-wrapper">
     <router-outlet>
       <!-- Whatever route you map in top-nav and side-nav will be rendered here -->
    </router-outlet>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is a great summary of how to use `<router-outlet>`.  However, the question asks for a solution _without_ `<router-outlet>`.

Comment: I think it addresses the need. Would be interesting to see solutions for the same problem without '<router-outlet>'